# Exclude long lines from grep results

Tags: grep

How do I exclude very long lines from `grep` results?

I often grep through lots of .js files (`-r`) and some of them are compiled, so they consist of a single line usually a couple thousand characters long. From all that clutter I find it hard to see the results from the rest of the files.

What should I pass to `grep` to exclude lines that are, say, more than 1000 character long?

I'd prefer not having to pipe the result through another grep, as that would make me lose colours from the output, or having to add the first grep at the end of the pipe again to get back the colours.

Comment: You could pipe it into `cut` but then you'd still lose the colors: `grep -r "foo"|cut -c 1000`.

Comment: You could switch to a better tool :-) [ack - grep on steroids](http://betterthangrep.com/) and then use this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2034806/17413

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Piping the `grep` to something won't necessarily get rid of the colors. That behavior results from `--color=auto` (which if you check `alias grep` is probably what you're using). You can override it and pass `--color=always` and `grep` will preserve the colors even through a pipe.

As far as excluding the lines, you could pipe to whatever tool you like (e.g. `cut` as Amazed mentioned). Keep in mind, that the colors from grep will insert extra bytes into the matched lines, if that matters to you.  There's no obvious way to (to me anyway) do it in the same `grep` invocation.

Comment: Yes, I have set `--color=auto` in my `.bashrc`. Using `--color=always` with `cut` did the trick.

Comment: Does the `cut` command not just output the specified characters from each line, not omit those lines? (i.e. chars 1-1000)

Answer (score 2):

The following command should achieve what you want, i.e. do not output matching lines whose length is greater than 1000 characters:

```
grep -r --color=always $pattern . | cut -c1-1000
```

The `--color=always` flag ensure that color escape sequences will be generated by grep.

This option default value is `--color=auto`, which makes grep color its output only if it is passed to an interactive terminal, and does not use colors when it's piped to another command.

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/113507/48906